# C#/VS Database Connection (Coming from PHP and Python/MySQL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio

So I have been doing some PHP and Python/Apache/MySQL (WAMP!) development for a while now, and I'm trying to branch out into C#, ASP.Net, IIS and MSSQL.

Anyway, I'm trying to figure out how the database connection works and how I add and edit tables in Visual Web Developer. I created the database in database explorer, but I don't see a way to add tables, or look at the columns set up. In addition, I have no real understanding of how the aspx page (I'm using Web Forms, but I'm willing to switch to MVC if it works better).

Basically my question is - how do I connect with and modify the database in Visual Studios/Visual Web Developer? In PHP it was all code, but here it seems to be mostly a visual (shocking, considering the name) method.

Comment: Try doing a search for 'c# working with databases'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to connect to sql server you still need a connection string, for example any of those you can find here depending on your server setup: http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

then you do not really need to use visual DragDroppable components, from the code you create a connection and a command object and for example you do the following, this is called ADO.NET

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(strconString))
{
    string cmdstr = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM dbo.Employee"

    using (var cmdselect = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(var dtr = cmdselect.ExecuteReader())
        {
           while (rdr.Read())
           {
              // here you use the values from the DataReader...
           }
        }
    }
}
```

this just to start, search about ADO.NET or SqlCommand here in StackOverflow, plenty of samples...

Answer (score 0):

So there is lot thing which are Visual, and Visual Studio generates code for you which is depend on the language you select for project. But behind the seen it's similar to any computer language.

Your question is very much related to learning and there are lot of material out there for Getting started.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-vb